# Extract substrings from each line. These substrings are in comma separated, "name=value" format

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression

I have  lines in a file that are comma separated. There are no column headers, it's mostly comma separated 'name=value' pairs. 
Here is some test data:

```
listoffruits,producelist,APPLE=red,BANNANA=yellow,GRAPE=purple,ORANGE=orange,FRUIT=yes,WATERMELON=green
listoffruits,producelist,APPLE=red,BANNANA=yellow,GRAPE=violet,ORANGE=orange,FRUIT=affirmative,WATERMELON=green
```

I would like to get the value for GRAPE=* and FRUIT=* to get the result:

```
purple yes
violet affirmative
```

Also I would like the ability to add more "columns" later (so not always GRAPE, FRUIT, but GRAPE, FRUIT and WATERMELON)

Another snag is the columns are not fixed. So I don't always know that WATERMELON is the last column.

The closest I got was from @jasonwryan:

```
awk -v RS="," -F= '/GRAPE/{a=$2}; /FRUIT/{b=$2} END{print a,b"\n"}'
```

but this outputs the last line     "violet affirmative" and not:

```
purple yes

violet affirmative
```

Comment: Are those files or streams? In any event, it significantly changes the required approach; you are probably best asking another question.

Comment: The solutions I give in my answer should all work with your new question. Next time, please make sure you explain your needs clearly so we don't waste time providing answers that don't help you.

Answer (score 4):

Some more choices. I have saved your example text in `file` for simplicity.

1. `grep` and PCREs:

   ```
   $ grep -oP '(GRAPE|FRUIT)=\K.*?(?=,)' file 
   purple
   yes
   violet
   affirmative
   ```

   To get them on the same line, just parse. For example

   ```
   $ grep -oP '(GRAPE|FRUIT)=\K.*?(?=,)' | paste -d" " - - –  
   purple yes
   violet affirmative
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   $ sed 's/.*GRAPE=\([^,]*\).*FRUIT=\([^,]*\).*/\1 \2/' file 
   purple yes
   violet affirmative
   ```

   Or, with GNU `sed`

   ```
   $ sed -r 's/.*GRAPE=([^,]*).*FRUIT=([^,]*).*/\1 \2/' file 
   purple yes
   violet affirmative
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -pne 's/.*GRAPE=([^,]*).*FRUIT=([^,]*).*/\1 \2/' file 
   purple yes
   ```

   You might notice the above is slightly similar to the `sed` one :). Alternatively:

   ```
   $ perl -lne '@f=(/(?:(?<=GRAPE=)|(?<=FRUIT=))(.+?),/g); print "@f"' file 
   purple yes
   violet affirmative
   ```

   This uses `,` as a field separator and searches all fields:

   ```
   $ perl -F, -lane '@r=grep(s/.+?=//, grep(/GRAPE|FRUIT/,@F)); print "@r"' file 
   purple yes
   violet affirmative
   ```

   This one is shorter but adds a leading space to each line:

   ```
   $ perl -F, -lane 'print grep(s/.+?=/ /, grep(/GRAPE|FRUIT/,@F));' file 
    purple yes
    violet affirmative
   ```

Comment: Your grep can be simpler: `grep -oP '(GRAPE|FRUIT)=\K.*?(?=,)' | paste -d" " - -`

Comment: @glennjackman yes indeed, much cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Awk:

```
awk -v RS="," -F= '/GRAPE/||/FRUIT/ {printf "%s ", $2}'
```

Changes the record separator from a new line to `,` and the field separator from a space to a `=`, then match lines that contain the pattern `GRAPE` or `FRUIT` and print the second matching field on the same line separated by a space. Result:

```
purple yes
```

Comment: @patronizing_bofh If you want to load more patterns and control the output, you're better off saving matches as variables and printing them at the end: `awk -v RS="," -F= '/GRAPE/{a=$2}; /FRUIT/{b=$2} END{print a,b"\n"}'`

Comment: @patronizing_bofh Please edit that in to your question: formatting in comments in sub par and it is difficult to parse.